# Filtering Firebase datasets with infiniteScroll with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Javascript (Ionic Framework) to load groups of Firebase sets (like Instagram), but I need to also filter the Firebase sets based on the value of the "sold" key in each data set. Here is one data set (there are many such sets):

[image]

The idea is if "sold" is false, then we load a given data set, if it's true, then we should not load it and skip it.

But there is a catch which makes this problem difficult. Please see the code next:

```
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {                                   
    if (this.end === false && (this.counter === 3 || this.counter === 8) && this.startListingID != undefined) {
      setTimeout(() => {                                                                              
        firebase.database().ref('/explore/').orderByKey().startAt((this.startListingID).toString()).limitToFirst(6).once('value', (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach(snap => {         
            if((this.counter <= (this.counter2 + 4)) && (this.intermediateListingID !== snap.val().listingID) && this.end === false) {
              let temp = {
                Item: snap.val().Item,
                Price: snap.val().price,
                displayName: snap.val().displayName,
                sold: snap.val().sold,
                listingID: snap.val().listingID }
              this.object.push(temp);
              this.counter++;
              this.intermediateListingID = snap.val().listingID;
              return false;
            } else {
              if(this.startListingID !== snap.val().listingID) {
                this.counter = this.counter2;
                this.startListingID = snap.val().listingID;
              }
              else { this.end = true; }
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
              infiniteScroll.complete();
            }, 1000);
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            infiniteScroll.complete();
          }, 1000);
        }).catch((error) => { console.log("infiniteScroll Error: " + JSON.stringify(error)); infiniteScroll.complete(); });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

I am just starting with coding, so I do realize the code above is rather bad, but it works.

The problem arises in cases where I would get "sold" data sets, and then the infinite scroll which is `limitToFirst(6)` turns to be less and the whole numbering logic screws up, not to mention if I get 6 sold data sets in a row, then nothing is shown and the scroll just breaks down.

If there a way (ideally on the level of Firebase) to FILTER all data sets with "sold = true" before they are fed into my infinite scroll logic?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace orderByKey with orderByChild('sold').equalTo(true)

```
firebase.database().ref('/explore/').orderByChild('sold').equalTo(true)
.limitToFirst(6).once('value', (snapshot) => {...
```

This should give you 6 items where *sold = true*. Unfortunately, you can't combine two filtering queries. So you'll either have to pull all the items and then just sort out which ones are sold after, or grab all the sold ones in random order. Though, if you're sorting by key this leads me to believe you don't need them sorted in any particular order, so you could go with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works well! But one more issue came around. I'm using ngOnInit() and firebase.database().ref('/explore/').orderByChild('sold').equalTo(false).limitToFirst(4).once('value', (snapshot) => { to load the first batch of data sets, and it gives me error that I can't use equalTo and StartAt together. In this case, how do I know where to continue loading more data sets after the original 3 have been loaded?

Comment: I had forgotten that startAt counted against the filtering. It actually isn't possible to combine the queries. You'll have to make a choice between one or the other, as Firebase does not allow filtering on more than one thing at a time. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it! It's such a pity that we can't combine the two. I really need them both here, and I can't load the whole Database, because I will have way too many data sets there, which will surely overload any system. Maybe there is a way to use "limitToFirst(X)" and dynamically change the number "X" based on how many have status "sold" already inside the Firebase call? Like if calling say 5 data sets, and one turns out to be "sold", then from within the call we can compensate with a +1 and have Firebase call one more data set for us?

Comment: You could complete the firebase call, find the number of unsold, remove them and just retrieve data from the last key you called previously. You don't have to do a call inside of the call though, just have it continue to call until you've reached the total you want. Infinite scrolling is a fairly easy task in firebase, you just change startAt and move up the initial value calls. Don't over complicate it.

Comment: Yeap, that's how I'm eventually implementing this. Actually, I already did this last night! Thanks a lot for your time and advice!;))) Enjoy your weekend!